# Inverse TextAppearance doesn't work

Tags: android, textview, android-theme

I've the following theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorHintInverse">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
```

And this `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/monthly_payment"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Inverse"/>
```

But it desn't work. The text color is still used from `android:textColor`. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing solution mentioned here..
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78184